# При обращении на сайт яндекса для получения токена flask выдает ошибку 400 Bad Request

Tags: python, post, flask, oauth

есть проблема. Делаю авторизацию через Яндекс ID на Flask. Хочу обменять код авторизации на OAuth токен. Делаю все по документации яндекса но при обращении на сайт не отдает токен и выдает ошибку 400 Bad request. Документация https://yandex.ru/dev/id/doc/dg/oauth/reference/auto-code-client.html#auto-code-client__get-token.

```
    def get_token_from_code(
    self, code: str, device_id: str | None = None,
    device_name: str | None = None
) -> Token:

    url = f'{self.BASE_URL}/token?{urlencode(self.__params)}'
    method = 'POST'
    data = {
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'code': code,
    }
    if device_id:
        try:
            DeviceID.validate(device_id)
        except InvalidDeviceID as e:
            self.log.error(e)
            raise e
        else:
            data['device_id'] = device_id
            if not device_name:
                warnings.warn(
                    'device_id is specified, but device_name is not. '
                    'Yandex ID returns token for unknown device.', UserWarning
                )
    if device_name:
        try:
            DeviceName.validate(device_name)
        except InvalidDeviceName as e:
            self.log.error(e)
            raise e
        else:
            data['device_name'] = device_name
            if not device_id:
                warnings.warn(
                    'device_name is specified, but device_id is not. '
                    'device_name will be ignored.', UserWarning
                )
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Basic {b64encode(f"{self._client_id}:{self._client_secret}".encode()).decode()}'
    }

    response = requests.post(url = url, data=data, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()
    if 'error' in response:
        match response['error']:
            case 'authorization_pending':
                raise AuthorizationPending(response['error_description'])
            case 'bad_verification_code':
                raise BadVerificationCode(response['error_description'])
            case 'invalid_client':
                raise InvalidClient(response['error_description'])
            case 'invalid_grant':
                raise InvalidGrant(response['error_description'])
            case 'invalid_request':
                raise InvalidRequest(response['error_description'])
            case 'invalid_scope':
                raise InvalidScope(response['error_description'])
            case 'unauthorized_client':
                raise UnauthorizedClient(response['error_description'])
            case 'unsupported_grant_type':
                raise UnsupportedGrantType(response['error_description'])
            case _:
                raise YandexOAuthError(response['error_description'])

    return response.json()
```